# set Rails environment url for selenium remote

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, capybara, minitest

I got selenium remote configured and running. I can access my development server (deployed with 'rails s') on '192.168.1.23:3000' from my computer using test methods like 'visit root_path' on capybara with minitest.

However, when I close my development server,  I can't access my test server while testing, I just get a chrome error with page not found

test file:

```
require "test_helper"
feature "dashboard" do
  scenario "test1", :js => true  do
  #Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host]= 'http://192.168.1.23:3000' 
  visit root_path
end
```

*Note: activating line 4 gives me nil when running visit root_path*

test_helper.rb

```
Capybara.configure do |config| 
  config.default_host = 'http://192.168.1.23:3000'
  config.app_host   = 'http://192.168.1.23:3000'
end
```

I've also [tried](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1275)
test environment, test.rb

```
Rails.application.default_url_options = {:host => "http://192.168.1.23:3000" }
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options = {:host => "http://192.168.1.23:3000" }
```

---

Edit:
I have rails server configured to listen to external addresses:

boot.rb

```
#this lets listen to some interfaces,
#https://fullstacknotes.com/make-rails-4-2-listen-to-all-interface/
require 'rubygems'  
require 'rails/commands/server'

module Rails  
  class Server
    alias :default_options_bk :default_options
    def default_options
      default_options_bk.merge!(Host: '192.168.1.23')
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Capybara runs the application on a random port, but you've set app_host to only connect on port 3000 (Which is the dev server default).  Rather than setting a fixed port in app_host set

```
Capybara.always_include_port = true
Capybara.app_host = 'http://192.168.1.23`
```

Then if the random port assignment isn't working due to firewall issues between your selenium remote and local machine you can set

```
Capybara.server_port = <some fixed port number the test app will get run on>
```

Comment: Didn't work. I can't connect, even assigning a server_port

Comment: When you assigned the server port can you access it from your machine on  http://192.168.1.23:<assigned port>  ??  Did you comment out your default_url_options settings?  Another thing to check is whether you need to set `Capybara.server_host`   by default it binds the server to 127.0.0.1 -- you may need to change that to bind to a different interface (whichever one 192.168.1.23 gets routed to)  I assumed it was 127.0.0.1 because you said `rails s` works.  Also, you haven't set  `Capybara.run_server = false` right?

Comment: I've removed: 'Rails.application.default_url_options...' and 'Rails.application.routes.default_url_options...'.  I can't access 192.168.1.23:3000 from either pc during rake test. Now I have : 'Capybara.always_include_port = true'  'Capybara.server_port = 3000'    Capybara.server_host = 'http://192.168.1.23'''Capybara.run_server = false'

Comment: by the way, I have previously modified rails server to listen to 192.168.1.23:3000. See edit

Comment: AH -- so set `Capybara.server_host='192.168.1.23'` and you need Capybara to run the server, so don't set run_server=false  -- and then you should be able to remove the Capybara.server_port = 3000 (or set it to something else, otherwise you won't be able to have your dev server running at the same time)

Comment: It worked!. To sum it up: Remove both 'Rails.application...' and change Capybara.configure only to Capybara.server_host='192.168.1.23' and Capybara.server_port = '4000'

Comment: @Gaston - and the `always_include_port=true` - glad to hear it's working